# Can't get up/down arrows to show in jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I've got the jQuery TableSorter 2.0 working so that clicking the column headers sort. But I cannot get the up/down arrows to show up. To simplify, I created a page using the sample from https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html. Here's the code for the test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Testing</title>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <link href="tablesorter/css/theme.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->


 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() 
            { 
                $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
            } 
        ); 
</script>    
 </head>
 <body>
 <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page in the browser (I've tried FireFox and Edge), the columns sort as expected but there are no up/down arrows.

I've looked at other posts about this problem, but the solutions either don't fit my situation or don't help.

I've tried this with and without the explicit CSS link, and with a couple of different themes I see in the css folder.

Comment: Is path to css valid? Why is it commented out?

Comment: Your code works fine when path to default theme css is valid http://plnkr.co/edit/L36bTYnTloJ6UDsc5O5B?p=preview

Comment: Yes, thanks. That works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `up/down` arrows are generated using the `css` file (the theme file).

You should use both the `bootstrap`'s css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/bootstrap-v3.min.css" />
```

And the `theme.css` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/theme.default.css" />
```

Comment: note there is no dependency on bootstrap unless set as theme option

Comment: @charlietfl bootstrap sets also the `th/tr` styles, so to make sure everything works there I think it's better to use it also, however you might be right and it's not required :)

Comment: can definietly use it, but is not required...see demo above. default also sets those styles

Comment: Added both stylesheet references and pointed to the cdn version for the bootstrap default theme. That combination has solved my problem.